# how to keep the hover background after the user moved the mouse until the transform finishes

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image, css-transforms

I got a div that changes its background to an image when a user hovers over it. The background is doing fine when the user hovers over it and the transform effect is applied smoothly, but when the user removes the mouse the image disappears suddenly.

I don't want it to happen and want the image to have a zoom out effect just like the Text inside the div and once the effect is finished the background changes to the default one and do not disappear suddenly without any effects.

How can I make it possible?

Here's my div:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container:hover .child,
.container:focus .child {
  background-image: url(https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/de7/energy-1-1176465.jpg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -o-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.container:hover .child:before,
.container:focus .child:before {
  display: block;
}
.child:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <span>Text</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is that you only apply the background image on hover, which means when you stop hovering the image no longer exists. I don't think what you want can be easily achieved with the route you're taking, there is no "background-opacity" property which would solve your issue. Take a look at my answer below, I've changed the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some simplified CSS using `display: grid` and putting the images in the HTML

- The image has `opacity: 0` to begin with, once hovered it goes to `opacity: 0.75`
- The image is the item that increases size on hover, this is so the text doesn't clip
- Change the hover accent by adding `style="--colorHover: red"` to any .container
- The gap between items is larger on bigger screens

Plus your browser will love you because the properties that change on hover won't trigger layout, and other than background-color it won't trigger paint! See here for more details https://csstriggers.com

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }


:root {
  --bgImg: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/de7/energy-1-1176465.jpg');
  --colorDefault: darkgray;
  --colorHover: black;
  --columnWidth: 1;
  --transTime: 660ms;
  --transFunc: cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
  --wrapperGap: 1rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { :root { --wrapperGap: 1.5rem } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { :root { --wrapperGap: 2rem } }

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: var(--wrapperGap);
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: var(--wrapperGap);
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: calc( ( var(--columnWidth) * 50% ) - ( var(--wrapperGap) / 2 ) ) ;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.child {
  background-color: var(--colorDefault);
  display: grid;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  place-items: center;

  transition: background-color var(--transTime) var(--transFunc);
}
.child > * { grid-area: 1/1/-1/-1 }
.child .txt {
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
.child .img {
  aspect-ratio: var(--columnWidth)/1;
  background-image: var(--bgImg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  transition: opacity calc(var(--transTime) * 2) var(--transFunc), transform var(--transTime) var(--transFunc);
}

.container:hover .child {
  background-color: var(--colorHover);
  transition: background-color var(--transTime) calc(var(--transTime) / 2) var(--transFunc);
}

.container:hover .child .img {
  opacity: 0.75;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: opacity var(--transTime) var(--transFunc), transform calc(var(--transTime) * 2) var(--transFunc);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">Original Image</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="--colorHover: green; --bgImg: url('https://picsum.photos/600?random=1');">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">Random One</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="--colorHover: blue; --bgImg: url('https://picsum.photos/600?random=2');">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">Random Two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="--colorHover: red; --bgImg: url('https://picsum.photos/600?random=3');">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">Random Three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="--columnWidth: 2; --colorHover: purple; --colorDefault: pink; --bgImg: url('https://picsum.photos/600?random=4');">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="img"></div>
      <div class="txt">Random Four (large)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine I think but if there is no real need to have the image in DOM, ie if it's there just for visual purposes, then you might consider using a similar method but on before and after pseudo elements as you can alter their opacities without affecting the element itself.

Comment: @AHaworth I edited the answer to use a `<div>` as the background, it's more performant than using `::before` or `::after`